# How to enable page builder in Magento 2.4.5?

Tags: configuration, magento2.4.5, page-builder, page-content, content

I am trying to enable Page Builder of admin section in Magento 2.4.5.
For this, I am trying to it as follow.
======backend=======
Store/Configuration/General/Content Management

By the way , there is no Advanced Content Tools item.
How to add section of Advanced Content Tools?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enable **Magento_PageBuilder** module in app/etc/config.php. The code looks like this:

```
'Magento_PageBuilder' => 1,
```

**OR**

Run the following command:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_PageBuilder
```

Run setup:upgrade command and Clear the cache.